# Proving limits using precise definition

Tags: calculus, limits

It's an example in Thomas's Calculus

Q. Prove that $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x)=4$

if
$f(x)=x^2, x\neq 2,
f(x)=1, x=2$

In the book they have proved it for $\varepsilon>4$ even when

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{4-\varepsilon} < x < \sqrt{4 + \varepsilon}
\end{equation}

My question is, if $\epsilon$ can't be greater than $4$ then how it can be proved for $\varepsilon>4$?

Comment: $\varepsilon$ is arbitray SMALL. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the $(\epsilon,\delta)$-definition. It says for **every** $\epsilon>0$, you must find a range of $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ such that all $x$ in this range **has the function value $f(x)$ whose distance to $f(x_0)$ is less than $\epsilon$**.

What makes you confuse is that you insist on applying the inequality in the case $\epsilon\le4$ to the case $\epsilon>4$, but please don't do this. Think the **intuitive meaning** deeper of the $(\epsilon,\delta)$-definition. For $\epsilon>4$, you can just take the interval $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ as in the case $\epsilon\le4$, and it still satisfies the $(\epsilon,\delta)$-definition so we are done.

I have the textbook. You can refer to the figure of that example for further understanding.

Generally speaking, if you have proven that this definition holds for some specific $\epsilon_0$, it in fact satisfies for all $\color{red}{\epsilon>\epsilon_0}$. You should get this point after realizing the spirit of the $(\epsilon,\delta)$-definition. Many people say it suffices to prove with an arbitrarily small $\epsilon>0$. That's because of this.

Comment: You have a typo. The correct version is "this definition holds for some specific $\epsilon _0$, it in fact satisfies for all $\epsilon>\epsilon _0$".

Comment: Uh, yeah your version is correct. I'll change it.

Comment: $\epsilon_0$ was some specific value as you mention. The definition requires that it be arbitrary and not specific.

Comment: It's my fault, thank you very much!

Comment: +1 for giving the secret of epsilon.

Comment: Well, according to the definition, |f(x)- L| should be smaller than ε. Even though ε>4 is not possible as it takes f(x) to a negative value and f(x) doesn't exist below zero but we shouldn't be concerned about it as |f(x)-L|<ε is true even for ε>4 since we are interested in showing that the inequality holds for ε>4 also. Existence of the function for any ε is not our concern. Is this what you want to say?

Comment: @SouravBhattacharya Your statement is too simplified. $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ must be accompanied with $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$. Don't focus on the inequality $\sqrt{4-\epsilon}<x<\sqrt{4+\epsilon}$. Realize the spirit of $(\epsilon,\delta)$-definition.

Comment: @Alan Tsai thanks

Answer (score 0):

i believe that its supposed to be that 0<ε<4 (smaller than 4, but still positive), and not the way you wrote it, but the general idea is to show that when ε is arbitray small-positive value, you can choose it to be smaller as you want, and the value the function f(x)=x² returns will be closer and closer to 4, as long as ε>0 (o.w if ε=0 you get the value √(4-ε)=√(4+ε)=2, which cause the value to be f(x)=1)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I agree with you, ε can't be greater than 4 but in Thomas' calculus they have proved it for ε >4 and ε >=4. That's why I asked it here

Comment: o.k, would you mind send a link to specific page?